# Swift's Array conformance to Collection

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, array-difference

Given two arrays of `RandomModelObject` that conform to Codable, Equatable and Hashable I want to calculate a diff between them and animate content changes in a UICollectionView. Having to support iOS 11 made me pick https://github.com/tonyarnold/Differ as a dependency for doing so.

This code:

```
class ScreenNameCollectionViewDataSource {
    var elements: [RandomModelObject] = []
}

extension ScreenNameViewController: ScreenNameViewModelDelegate {
    func elementsStoreUpdated() {
        collectionView.animateItemAndSectionChanges(oldData: dataSource.elements,
                                                    newData: viewModel.blablabla, 
                                                    updateData: {
            dataSource.elements = viewModel.blabla
        })
    }
}
```

Produces 2 errors:

```
Instance method 'animateItemAndSectionChanges(oldData:newData:indexPathTransform:sectionTransform:updateData:completion:)' requires that 'RandomModelObject.Element' conform to 'Equatable'

Instance method 'animateItemAndSectionChanges(oldData:newData:indexPathTransform:sectionTransform:updateData:completion:)' requires that 'RandomModelObject' conform to 'Collection'
```

The errors don't seem to point me anywhere - Array is a Collection and the model conforms to Equatable. Did I miss anything there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `animateItemAndSectionChanges`, which not only requires that `T` is a `Collection`, but it also requires that `T`'s elements are `Collection`s. In other words, `T` needs to be something like a 2D array.

This is because `animateItemAndSectionChanges` handles both rows and sections. The 2D collection will tell the method what the old and new rows and sections are. Each "inner" collection represents a section.

Since your data source is a 1D array, it seems like you just need `animateRowChanges`, which is for single-section table views.

If each `RandomModelObject` actually represents a *section*, then you need to `map` each one of those to an array, so that you get a `[[Something]]`, and change the `updateData` closure accordingly.

Comment: oh, that was something that I did not figure out by reading the docs, animateItemChanges worked just fine. Thanks!